# Sorting by only the most recent object

Tags: django, django-models

Models.py

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        article_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        content = models.TextField()
        date_published = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=timezone.now)
        game = models.ForeignKey('library.Game', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        article_image = models.ImageField(default='/media/default.png', upload_to='article_pics')
        platform = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Game(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.TextField()
        date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        cover = models.ImageField()
        cover_display = models.ImageField(default='default.png')
        developer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
```

Views.py

```
'recent': Game.objects.all().order_by('-post__date_published')[:5],
```

How can I retrieve the most recent post for each game and then sort the games by the most recent post's date published? I'm currently using whats in the views.py but it sorts all posts and will return duplicates if a certain game has many recent posts.

Entire views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from library.models import Game
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView
)

# Create your views here.
def home(request):

    context = {
        'recent': Game.objects.all().order_by('-post__date_published')[:5],
        'recent_posts1': Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_published')[:1],
        'recent_posts2': Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_published')[1:2],
        'recent_posts3': Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_published')[2:3],
    }
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)

class TitlePostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'main/title_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5


    def get_queryset(self):
        title = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return Post.objects.filter(game=title).order_by('-date_published')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TitlePostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['game'] = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return context

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

Comment: Can you please share your code of the views.py?

Comment: Added my entire views.py

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, just specify that you need unique elements

```
'recent': Game.objects.all().order_by('-post__date_published').distinct()[:5],
```

Comment: Sorry I had the wrong code I was using in my views.py. I have edited it to reflect what I'm currently using to sort my games.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have sent multiple recent post, where you could send it in a single context. Now addressing your problem, when you have multiple posts of same game. Its easily resolvable by using [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct), if you are using Postgresql. For example like this:

```
context = {
    'recent': Game.objects.all().order_by('-post__date_published')[:5],
    'recent_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_published').distinct('game')[:5]
}
```

And in template use it like this:

```
{% for post in recent_posts %}
    Last {{ forloop.counter }} Post: {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

But if you are not using postgresql, it will bit complicated. But, it can be done like this:

```
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_published')
recent_post = []
for post in posts:
   if not filter(lambda x:x.game == post.game, recent_post):
      recent_post.append(post)
   if len(recent_post) == 5:
      break

context = {
    'recent': Game.objects.all().order_by('-post__date_published')[:5],
    'recent_posts': recent_post
}
```